# Is my statistical model correct?

Tags: probability, self-study

I have to construct a statistical model for the random variable $X=(X_1,X_2) \sim N(\mu+\alpha_1,1) \times N(\mu +\alpha_2,1), \mu \in \Bbb R, \alpha_i \in \Bbb R$ and tell if it's identifiable.

What I came up with is the following:
$(S, \mathscr P)$ (where $S$ is the state space and $\mathscr P$ is the family of pdfs) $= (\Bbb R^2, \{\Bbb P_{\theta} : \theta =(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3) \in \Theta=\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R = \Bbb R^3 \})$ , since

$\theta_1 = \mu \in \Bbb R$
,$\theta_2= \alpha_1 \in \Bbb R$,
$\theta_3= \alpha_2 \in \Bbb R$

Also, the statistcial model is identifiable since $\theta \neq \theta' \Rightarrow \Bbb P_\theta \neq \Bbb P_{\theta'}$

Is my reasoning correct?

**Edit** Actually I made a mistake and the model is not identifiable since if we put $\theta^{'}= (0,1,1)$ and $\theta^{"}=(1,0,0)$ then the mean(and hence the distribution) is the same but the parameters are not the same. Hence the model is unidentifiable

Comment: Could you explain what a "statistical model" is supposed to have in addition to your parameterization of the distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$?  And by "$\times$" would you mean a Cartesian product instead of a numerical product?

Comment: @whuber well a statistical model in my textbook is defined as the following:

The pair $\{(S;f_{\theta} : \theta \in \Theta)\}$ is called statistical model, where $S$
is the state space/support (of data) and $\{f_{\theta} : \theta \in \Theta)\}$  is the family of pmfs/pdfs, describing the family
of distributions assumed to contain the distribution of the realised random variable. parameterised
by a parameter $\theta \in \Theta$, with $\Theta$ being the parameter space.

Comment: @whuber Also, the $\times$ symbol is not a cartesian product. It is just said that $X = (X_1,X_2)$ where both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the normal distribution as defined above

Comment: That's exactly what the Cartesian product is.  A numerical product would result in a univariate distribution.  Presumably you intend $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be independent.

Comment: @whuber well actually it is not said in the exercise explicitly whether they are independent. And thanks for the remark!

Comment: I would guess, than, that the notation is intended to mean that $(X_1,X_2)$ has a bivariate Normal distribution with mean $(\mu+\alpha_1,\mu+\alpha_2),$ unit variances, and zero covariance. You have already pointed to an example of the fact that this is the same distribution as the one with mean $((\mu+c)+(\alpha_1-c), (\mu+c)+(\alpha_2-c))$ for any real number $c.$